# 「時間」「約束」「用事」の修飾 (Noun modification for these 3 nouns)

Tags: grammar, verbs, tense, modification

## 日本語

動詞で修{しゅう}飾{しょく}するときには、「た」や「ない」などの形の動詞が使えるでしょう。

> ミラーさんが　**住んで　いた**　うちに　ねこが　いました。

でも「みんなの日本語」（第22課）によると、「時間」や「約束」や「用事」の場合はいつも辞書形の動詞で修飾します。

> 朝ごはんを　食べる　**時間**
>
> 映画を　見る　**約束**
>
> 市役所へ 行く **用事**

辞書形を使わなければならない名詞は、ほかにありますか。

以下の文章は全部おかしいですか。

> 朝ごはんを　**食べた**　時間
>
> 映画を　**見た**　約束
>
> 市役所へ **行った** 用事

## English

Noun modification can be done by verbs that aren't in dictionary form.

> ミラーさんが　**住んで　いた**　うちに　ねこが　いました。

However Minna no Nihongo (Lesson 22) says that the following nouns take on dictionary-form verbs:

> 朝ごはんを　食べる　**時間**
>
> 映画を　見る　**約束**
>
> 市役所へ 行く **用事**

Are there other nouns like these?

Are these wrong?

> 朝ごはんを　**食べた**　時間
>
> 映画を　**見た**　約束
>
> 市役所へ **行った** 用事

Comment: 朝ご飯を食べた時間は、昨日は遅かった is natural. And 去年した約束 and 昨日出来た用事 is natural, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you think the plain (non conjugated) form is used in those examples? It's not the nouns that are special per se, as I think you can see from your attempt at giving counter examples. Some other trivial counter examples: 過ごした時間・交わした約束・終わった用事. Try thinking about the difference between すること and したこと to see why it's not the nouns that are special.

Comment: @Brandon "When expressing the time for doing some activity, the dictionary form of the action is placed before じかん". That's from my book... I don't really understand why this was written, though. Perhaps this rule applies under certain circumstances?

Comment: @YuuichiTam yes, personally I think so... but after reading the rule in my comment above, I'm having trouble seeing when じしょ form needs to be used

Comment: @rhyaeris I think you may forget the rule. 映画を見た約束 is very unnatural because can you promise the past action? And nai-form is used like テレビを見ない時間, アメリカに行かない約束.

Comment: As far as aspect/tense conjugation (like 食べる→食べた) is concerned, I think this has a lot to do with whether the modifying clause in which the verb appears is an appositive or relative clause, and in the case of appositive clauses, the time reference of the head noun (e.g. 約束 is always about the future; thus the apposition 映画を見た約束 shows temporal conflict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[このページ](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=KWod-7mqDGAC&pg=PA215&lpg=PA215&dq=%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8%E5%BD%A2%E3%80%80%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%80%80%E7%B4%84%E6%9D%9F%E3%80%80%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%8B&source=bl&ots=VXZuK3BWtf&sig=8zvnQzOv524rTNCQIs8KDKEaQXU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjihrj9l8zMAhWEMKYKHeV-DpoQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E%E8%BE%9E%E6%9B%B8%E5%BD%A2%E3%80%80%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%80%80%E7%B4%84%E6%9D%9F%E3%80%80%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%8B&f=false)を見ると、

> 約束・予定されている用事の内容、時間の用途などを説明するとき動詞の辞書形で修飾節を作る。

とありますので、このルールは、「『約束・予定されている用事の内容、時間の用途』やそれに準ずる内容のことをいう場合には辞書形を使いなさい」ということだと思います。

> 以下の文章は全部おかしいですか。Are these wrong?
>
> 朝ごはんを　食べた　時間
>
> 映画を　見た　約束
>
> 市役所へ 行った 用事

「朝ご飯を食べた時間」は、おかしくないと思います。この場合は、「時間の用途」(the time for doing some activity) ではなく、「その行動をする時間」(the time when an action takes place) を表す表現になるので、「時間の用途などを説明するとき動詞の辞書形で修飾節を作る」というルールに当てはまらないため、「食べた」を使うことができるのだと思います。

「終わった用事」に関しても、「予定されている用事の内容」を表していませんし、「交わした約束」も「約束の内容」を表していませんし、「過ごした時間」も「時間の用途」を表していませんので、このルールに当てはまらないため、「た形」を使うことができるのだと思います。

「映画を見た約束」「市役所へ行った用事」は、ちょっと変な感じがします。

> 辞書形を使わなければならない名詞は、ほかにありますか。

「予定」「つもり」などはどうでしょうか。上の例と同じように、「予定の内容・するつもりである行動の内容」を表す場合ですが。例えば…

> 明日は、母と買い物に行く予定があります。
> 今日は、９時までに帰るつもりです。

「約束・予定の内容、時間の用途」とはあまり関係がなさそうですが、「権利」「勇気」「意志」「意図」、あるいは「手紙」(手紙の内容を説明するときに)などにも、辞書形がよく使われると思います。例えば…

> 発言する権利
> 立ち向かう勇気
> 実行する意志
> ～～という手紙

このような形で使われる語は、他にもいろいろありそうです。

それから、コメントでも言われているように、「ない形」を使うこともできると思います。例えば…

> 彼とは、もう二度と会わない約束をしました。
> 何もしない時間。
> 今日は一日、どこにも行かない予定/つもりです。

(ルールに当てはまるような、「～しない用事」の例は、ちょっと思いつきません・・・)

Comment: 約束・予定されている用事の内容、時間の用途ですね。 明確な説明でよく考えたあとで目があきました。どうもありがとうございました。